# Confusion about finding the CDF for this function .

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $X$ be a continous random variable with the following PDF $$f(x) = \begin{cases}
x& \mbox{for} \quad 0 \leq x < 1 \\
 2-x &\mbox{for} \quad 1 \leq x < 2\\
0 &\mbox{}\text{elsewhere}
\end{cases}$$

Then the CDF will be  :

$$F(x) = \begin{cases} 0 &\mbox{for}\quad x< 0  \\ \frac{1}{2}x^2 & \mbox{for}\quad 0\leq x< 1\\1- \frac{1}{2} (2-x)^2&\mbox{for}\quad 1\leq x< 2 \\ 1 &\mbox{for}\quad  x \geq  2 \end{cases}   $$ .

I did not get the idea that the CDF for $\quad 1\leq x< 2$ will be $1- \frac{1}{2} (2-x)^2$ , how can I prove that  for $\quad 1\leq x< 2$ the CDF $F(x)= \int_{1}^{x}(2-x)dx + F(1) = 1- \frac{1}{2} (2-x)^2$ ? .

Comment: Your density is not well defined. The first lines implies it will be negative, whilst the second line covers an overlapping region with the first.

Comment: @Bey I edited it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, the CDF is the integral of your density up to that point:

$$\int_0^1 x \;dx + \int_1^k 2-x \;dx = 1/2 + \left[2x-\frac{x^2}{2}\right]_1^k = 1/2 + 2k-k^2/2-2+1/2 =$$
$$1+(-k^2/2+2k-2)$$

Can you simplify from there?

Comment: Great thanks , just one more question , $F(1)$ by the definition of CDF will be $P(X\leq 1) = P(X<1) + P(x=1) $, how can I calculate it , I mean the second part $P(x=1) $

Comment: @BahgatNassour start by deriving a formula for $P(1-a<X\leq 1+a)$ for small positive $a$ and then take the limit as $a \to 0$